# Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 with JMF and Eclipse when exporting as JAR

Tags: eclipse, jar, nullpointerexception, jmf

I am writing a short program to extract images from a webcam using the Java Media Framework (JMF).

It seems like I have run into a problem that many people had before me, but to which there doesn't exist a clearly formulated solution. I am using eclipse and there my program works fine. I have added jmf.jar as an external library.

Now, the problem is that if I export my program as a jar I get the following error when running it on the command line:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at recorder.SimpleRecorder.<init>(SimpleRecorder.java:46)
    at recorder.SimpleRecorder.main(SimpleRecorder.java:67)
```

Line 46 is `ml = di.getLocator();`. (I have included the code below.)

This is the same error that I get when I don't add jmf.jar as an external library and try to run the program in eclipse.

Some recources on the internet, like this one

https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1277297

suggest that the file jmf.properties is the source of the problem. I therefore tried several things that the above resource suggested:

- Add the path of the jmf.properties file to the manifest of the jar. After that the manifest looks like:

  Manifest-Version: 1.0

  Class-Path: . "C:\Program Files (x86)\JMF2.1.1e\lib\jmf.properties"

  Main-Class: recorder.SimpleRecorder

  I am not sure if that is the right way to add a path to the manifest.
- I also tried to remove the jmf.jar from the folder C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\lib, as having it there seemed to cause problems in eclipse because it was jmf was available twice (leaving it ther and not adding the jmf.jar as an external library lead to the above error).
- Adding jmf.properties to the folder in which the jar file is located produced a different error:

  Exception in thread "VFW Request Thread" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: JMFSecurityManager: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jmvfw in java.library.path
      at com.sun.media.JMFSecurityManager.loadLibrary(JMFSecurityManager.java:206)
      at com.sun.media.protocol.vfw.VFWCapture.(VFWCapture.java:19)
      at com.sun.media.protocol.vfw.VFWSourceStream.doConnect(VFWSourceStream.java:241)
      at com.sun.media.protocol.vfw.VFWSourceStream.run(VFWSourceStream.java:763)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
- Copying the jmf.properties file into any other location, including inside the jar (as suggested in the above resource) did not have any effect.

I hope someone knows how to solve that - I am more than happy to supply more information.

Thanks,

Jonas

```
package recorder;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import javax.media.Buffer;
import javax.media.CaptureDeviceInfo;
import javax.media.CaptureDeviceManager;
import javax.media.Manager;
import javax.media.MediaLocator;
import javax.media.Player;
import javax.media.control.FrameGrabbingControl;
import javax.media.format.VideoFormat;
import javax.media.util.BufferToImage;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.JPEGCodec;
import com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.JPEGEncodeParam;
import com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.JPEGImageEncoder;

public class SimpleRecorder extends JFrame{

public static Player player = null;
public CaptureDeviceInfo di = null;
public MediaLocator ml = null;
public Buffer buf = null;
public Image img = null;
public VideoFormat vf = null;
public BufferToImage btoi = null;

public SimpleRecorder(String title) {
    super(title);

    String str2 = "vfw:Microsoft WDM Image Capture (Win32):0";
    di = CaptureDeviceManager.getDevice(str2);

    if(di == null) System.out.println("di is null.");

    ml = di.getLocator();

    try 
    {
      player = Manager.createRealizedPlayer(ml);
      player.start();
      Component comp;

      if ((comp = player.getVisualComponent()) != null)
      {
        add(comp,BorderLayout.CENTER);
      }

    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    SimpleRecorder frame = new SimpleRecorder("Simple Recorder");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setSize(335,275);
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame.setVisible(true);

    frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
          public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
          playerclose();
          System.exit(0);}});

    System.out.println("Waiting for camera to get ready...");

    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("Start recording...");
    while(true){

        frame.recordImage();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(350);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }   
}

private void recordImage(){

     // Grab a frame
      FrameGrabbingControl fgc = (FrameGrabbingControl)
      player.getControl("javax.media.control.FrameGrabbingControl");
      buf = fgc.grabFrame();

      // Convert it to an image
      btoi = new BufferToImage((VideoFormat)buf.getFormat());
      img = btoi.createImage(buf);

      // Get current directory
      String currentDir = new File("./Extracted_Image.jpg").getAbsolutePath();

      // save image
      saveJPG(img,currentDir);
}

public static void saveJPG(Image img, String s)
  {
    BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D g2 = bi.createGraphics();
    g2.drawImage(img, null, null);

    FileOutputStream out = null;
    try
    { 
      out = new FileOutputStream(s); 
    }
    catch (java.io.FileNotFoundException io)
    { 
        System.out.println("File Not Found"); 
    }

    if(out == null) System.out.println("Could not create file output stream.");

    JPEGImageEncoder encoder = JPEGCodec.createJPEGEncoder(out);
    JPEGEncodeParam param = encoder.getDefaultJPEGEncodeParam(bi);
    param.setQuality(0.5f,false);
    encoder.setJPEGEncodeParam(param);

    try 
    { 
      encoder.encode(bi); 
      out.close(); 
    }
    catch (java.io.IOException io) 
    {
      System.out.println("IOException"); 
    }
  }

public static void playerclose() 
  {
    player.close();
    player.deallocate();
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

One thing to check would be your eclipse.ini.   I've see problems where the workspace's installed-jre doesn't agree with the eclipse.ini specified vm.  If ini uses 1.6 and workspace uses 1.7 then some eclipse plugins may attempt to process 1.7 bytecode or source with 1.6 tools resulting in a variety of problems

- Edit \eclipse.ini
- Check vm set to expected version

  -vm
  c:/java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre/bin/server/jvm.dll